# Configure subdirs with another flags using automake & autoconf

Tags: autoconf, automake

I'm working on project, that uses *automake&autoconf*. Now I need to add a third-party library, that located in subdirectory '`mylib`'. That library has it's own '`configure`' script and requires speacial flags.
So, my project configure should be used like this way:

```
./configure --with-aaa=no --enale-bbb=yes --enable-ccc=yes
```

But the third-party library shoould be configured with another flags:

```
./configure --enable-ddd=yes
```

**How can I add subdirectory with my library to configure script of my project, but let library to be configured with it's own flags?**

I looked through autoconf & automake  abilities and found only `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS(mylib)`, that will only run `./configure` script of library with flags of my project, but that's wrong.